# Python - creating subpackage without exposing internal imports

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have following structure:

```
/api
    /v0
        api_1.py
        api_2.py
    /v1
        api_1.py
        api_2.py
```

I would like to use it like that:

```
import api

api.v0.api_1.notify_user('1337')
```

However when I do for example `dir(api.v0.api_1)`, I will get not only the API methods but all the imports that are performed inside. I feel other developers should not be bothered of what I use internally.

One of the solutions I am considering is to change all internal imports in api_1 to something like that:

```
import collections as _collections
```

to clearly indicate it's not a part of a public API. However, this seems to be very strange.

How should I solve this puzzle? Or maybe I should not bother at all and what I am trying to achieve is an overkill?

Comment: I think you shouldn't bother at all.

Comment: You can use `__init__.py` files and the `__all__` attribute to define what a package exposes externally; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/44834/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/448271/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need to import public stuff in `__init__.py`. File structure should look so:

```
/api
    /v0
       __init__.py # import public stuff here
       api_1.py
       api_2.py
    /v1
       __init__.py
       api_1.py
       api_2.py
```

In the code:

```
api.v0.notify_user('1337')
```

Comment: That is the thing I end up using.